# White haze around laptop OLED screen

Tags: laptop, display, oled

I have an HP Envy x360 with a 13 inch OLED touch screen. When I turned on my laptop just now, I noticed that there is a white haze running almost at the edges of the screen. It wasn't there yesterday.

- It's not a driver issue. Tried booting Linux, problem persists.
- Not visible on screenshots.
- There is no such haze on the external TV that I connected.
- It is only perceptible on the gray areas. No haze on black areas of the screen.
- Tried googling, but couldn't find anyone with quite the same problem as me.

Is there any hope for me?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This looks like it *might* be screen delamination, where layers are peeling apart: https://blog.agdisplays.com/index.php/2022/09/12/touchscreen-delamination-cause-effect-and-repair/ . Check if it's in warranty, or even if not, if the HP will help anyway.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, seems like a clue. Will follow it up.